# Version 9 - delete edge from Delaunay Graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have a problem with subgraph in Mathematica 9. In Ver10 the below code works :

```
(****************************************************)
dist = 1.1;(*when the distance is grather then dist edge is deleted*) 
a = {0, 1, 2 I}; 
coordReal = {Re@#, Im@#} & /@ a;
N=Length[a]; 
planar = DelaunayMesh[coordReal]["AdjacencyMatrix"]; 
Do[
   Do[If ABS{[a[[j]]-a[[i]]] > dist, 
      planar[[j, i]] = 0],
   {i,1,N}],
{j,1,N}]; 
GraphPlot[planar, VertexLabeling -> False,   VertexCoordinateRules -> coord]
(**************************************************)
```

Is a way to use this method in Mathematica Ver9?

Answer (score 3):

It helps to use proper syntax. For example, `N` is a built-in symbol and cannot be overwritten. Moreover, it is `Abs` not `ABS` and all kinds of bracketing have to match. The following seems to work.

```
dist = 1.1;
a = {0, 1, 2 I};
coordReal = {Re@#, Im@#} & /@ a;
n = Length[a];
planar = DelaunayMesh[coordReal]["AdjacencyMatrix"];
Do[
  If[Abs[a[[j]] - a[[i]]] > dist, planar[[j, i]] = 0],
  {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}];
GraphPlot[planar, VertexLabeling -> False, VertexCoordinateRules -> coordReal]
```

## Edit

In version 9, the issue is that `MeshRegion` and `DelaunayMesh` are absent because they were only introduced in version 10.0. The now superseded package "ComputationalGeometry`" provides a function`DelaunayTriangulation` that returns the vertex adjacency list of the Delaunay triangulation. From this, the adjacency matrix can be built as follows.

```
Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"];
planar = SparseArray[Join @@ Thread /@ DelaunayTriangulation[coordReal] -> 1];
```

The rest should work. Notice however that `GraphPlot` has also been updated with version 10; since I am running version 11.3, I cannot test it.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Did you use Normal for output ony or did it make any deeper sense?. Without it works good too. Regards, Olaf.

Comment: No special purpose. I was expecting that you are more familiar with conventional matrices than with `SparseArray`s. Whenever you have a graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges with $m \ll n^2$, then using a `SparseArray` for the adjacency matrix is actually preferable because it uses only $n + 2 m$ instead of $n^2$ memory.